# Shrinking-type garden hose suddenly stopped flowing

Tags: water, hose

I thought I was pretty good around the house (after all just finished a remodel of my whole bathroom!)...
I recently bought one of those shrinking/expanding type of 100' garden hose. It worked fine for a couple weeks.
Then yesterday I had let it run my sprinkler for several hours at a low flat rate, turned it off, moved the sprinkler, turned it back on again, and... nothing.

Not a single drop of water.

They claim the hose cannot kink, but I scrutinized the entire length anyway. But, true to its word, there were no kinks.

I took off the sprinkler to eliminate that variable. I turned the water off at the spigot and the hose shrunk just like it was supposed to. Turning the water back on and the hose expanded like it was supposed to. At the far end of the hose, this model has an on/off valve which, when turned, I can see the ball valve inside opening and closing.

So I am at a loss; it is a nice hose, for sure, but if it is not willing to deliver any water for me...

Answer (score 1):

I had one of those once - it lasted about 20 minutes until the inner hose found a nick in the outer casing and exploded in a hilarious fashion.

Those hoses are made of a super-soft squishy plastic tube (think of the plastic that makes up one of those translucent squeezy toys you'd get in a coin machine) inside a woven outer casing.  The problem is that inner tube is extremely delicate.  My guess is having been left outside, it may have become hot enough to melt itself shut close to the end.

Comment: What  Chris O says sounds plausible. However if there was water running through the hose I would think that it cooled the inner hose enough so as not to reach it's melting point.  If it had the hose would expand only to that point and the remaining hose would be limp. Michael Sorens (OP) does not indicate that is the case. He says as well that he can look into the ball valve and see that it is open.  Therefore  I have to say this hose defies the laws of hydrodynamics.

Comment: could have a piece of crap or rubber in there blocking the ball valve -- stick something through it to check.

Comment: :laughing-out-loud: